# Python + WebDriver — Several browsers launched while using unittest module

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

Could you please clarify how can i use several methods(tests) in terms of the same single browser process (following code execute opening 2 browsers one by one):

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class Regression(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def test_op(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

    def test_second(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com/")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs on unittest: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

The setUp() and tearDown() methods allow you to define instructions that will be executed before and after each test method.

Meaning that your setUp() code is runs twice in your example.
If you want to re use the same browser instance move your driver initialization to a setUpClass() method that will only run once per test class

Comment: I tried to define everything inside setUp method and assign only driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com/") for each method. But in this case i have obvious unresolved reference = driver, since i didn't use driver = self.driver anymore.